# Sending request to a specific port on Remote Server

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I can send request on specific port using TeraTerm but
I want to instantiate Tera Term through CLI without giving me any GUI pop up. As you can see in the picture its using other option as a Service, what kind of connection service it is using? Protocol is unspec as well, what is the protocol?

Is there any linux in built utility that I can use (I don’t have rights to install any utility in Server). Any other ideas how I can post request on a specific port that is running my service?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zoHH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

Echo “msg” > /dev/tcp/host/port